# Lower the reputation threshold for approving/rejecting edits

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, privileges

I feel like I started getting the following error more often lately while trying to edit posts:

> There are [too many pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue) on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.

Being that only users with > 2000 reputation could approve/reject edits. That only ends up being .73% of the site for [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/). If this would be lowered to > 1000 for example, then it would almost double to 1.32%.

I think that a user that has 1000/1500 reputation is already pretty established on the site.
We already let users with lower reputation do first questions and answers etc. Maybe we should drop the threshold to > 1500 or > 1000 and this would add much more reviewers to the site and therefore improve the quality of posts.

Comment: I would really appreciate if people could add some context to why it's a bad idea. Thanks!

Comment: I would rather make it higher because a lot of user with > 2000 are doing very bad edits

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think this just proves that reputation is not everything.. There is always going to be people even with high reputation that are going to do a bad job..

Comment: so the higher we make it the better is since we are reducing the number of users allowed to edits and for all the others we can still revert their edits or rectify them. In all the cases, we have less garbage

Comment: Or the more users you allow to approve it. You have more people fixing the garbage and revert the bad ones.

Comment: No, it means more bad reviews for already understaffed moderators to sift through. Hell, mods do not keep up with the current review volume. Lower rep in suggested edits means more bad reviews _and_ less ability to deal with said bad reviews. Loss-loss.

Comment: Don't get fooled by your own percentage numbers, SO has _a lot_ of dead rep 1 accounts. When you want proper numbers you need to filter for active accounts first. The numbers won't go through the roof then, but would be more reliable.

Comment: "I think that a user that has 1000/1500 reputation is already pretty established on the site" and yet the comment on this post indicate opposite. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info to join that "pretty established on the site" club.

Comment: No because there is an upper bound on the number of edits can go into the queue. More reviewers only means that more people can push edit suggestions into it, it won't change anything worthwhile. Based on what you say I would rather look at what the point is where your edits no longer need reviewing. That might actually lower the workload, somewhat. It remains wonky though because reputation simply isn't a reliable retarder. Some people take years to get to 1k rep, some people take a week.

Comment: @Gimby, my point is to let more people *approve* the suggested edits.

Comment: @BeeFriedman and my point is that this is pointless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### I would rather see a path to gaining the privilege that has nothing to do with reputation.

For example (numbers completely made up; I have not attempted to assess via SEDE how many users would qualify, although if someone wants to, that would be delightful...), anyone who has had at least 90% of at least 100 suggestions approved gets the ability to edit without review and also to review suggested edits.

Comment: Wow, I really like the idea! Good point!

Comment: I really didn't like the way everybody commenting here used reputation as way to measure quality. It's definitely a starting point, but your solution is much more reasonable.

Comment: @BeeFriedman you'd actually be surprized how many of us are outspoken for the reputation to be abolished as a measurement of "worthiness" in unlocking various privileges on the site.

Comment: Maybe combing the two would be a perfect solution, e.g. Users need a minimum of X amount of reputation (which shows that they know their way around the site) and %90 of suggestions approved etc. (which shows that they know how to edit posts).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine good to know, because if you read through all the responses to my post it seems like this is what most people care about, but I guess my assumption was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Unless I messed things up, here you go, Ryan: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1673142) (configurable). If what I am seeing is correct, I'd be hella happy with the new system :)

Comment: @BeeFriedman well, they aren't necessary against switching from reputation entirely and are just opposing the idea of *reducing* the threshold further, which I agree won't help things as the privilege being reputation-based as opposed to be merit-based is *exactly* the core issue with the system. We get a lot of garbage reviews because anyone who simply crossed the threshold is considered good enough to review edits of others. In reality, half (understated) of those reviews have to be suspended indefinitely from reviewing to stop the damage they do on a regular basis.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine ooh, thanks :-) from [a quick tweak](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1673235/merit-based-and-rep-based-full-edit-privileges-eligibility-comparison), it looks like those particular numbers would add 744 _additional_ eligible editors who've accessed the site at least once in 2022 (regardless of whether they did anything).  Not a lot, but not zero.  It'd be a start :-)  And of course, it might be an incentive for the right people.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I've seen many bad questions and answers written by 1000+ rep users here

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine, but If you wanna use a system like this why do you still need > 2000 rep, why can't you reduce it to a lower number e.g. > 1000 plus %90 accepted?

Comment: @RyanM you are welcome :) Yeah, frankly, I am not concerned too much about adding new reviewers as opposed to clearing the ranks of existing ones that got the privilege just because they are "rich" enough (the fact that many still don't see the problem with reputation being essentially an income qualification is beyond me).

Comment: @Esther ofc - because reputation is simply not a measurement of quality, yet SE chose it as a backbone of their system (not surprizing from a USA company). Not in any way whatsoever (it's true that it corresponds with the number of users helped [and even at that - it does not tell us anything about content *quality*, just that it's popular] by posting content).

Comment: @BeeFriedman where did you see reputation in the merit-based system we are talking about (removing it from the equation entirely is precisely the point of what we are discussing with RyanM here)? :) It's only present in the subquery in the select statement to get the number of eligible users under the *current* system (that exists since times immemorial).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine my bad...

Comment: @BeeFriedman no worries, it's a bit of a complex query to parse quickly. Anyways, the point being, that many of us share the frustration about needing a steady income of imaginary internet points to be able to curate the site. I am sure we lost a lot of potentially great curators because they simply got disappointed when they realized that to clean up the site they need to become the problem in the first place. And don't get me started on the quality of reviews of many of those who are eligible under the current system...

Comment: Yeah, the issue is basically that being good at writing questions/answers (what's measured by rep) does not necessarily have a lot to do with skill as an edit reviewer/editor.

Answer (score 12):

The more people you have doing this, the less (hypothetical) guarantees you can make about the thoroughness of the review that's taking place.

Comment: Ok, but there has to be a balance. If users could already review Triage questions why not allow them to do this as well...

Comment: This *is* the balance.  If it went any higher then the queue would *never* be emptied!

Comment: Yeah, so maybe it should be lowered a little like 1500 and the quality of edits won't be affected. Who says that 2000 is the perfect balance?

Comment: I'd rather have it go *higher*, personally.  Not having it go higher is the balance I think that should be struck.